# Unexpected Python version in VS Code Terminal

Tags: python, macos, vscode-python

I just installed VS Code, Python (version 3.7.5 released on Oct.15, 2019) on MacOS.
So I run `python --version` on my VS Code Terminal, the result showed `Python 2.7.11`.

Shouldn't it be 3.7.5?

Comment: How about running `python3 --version`? Probably you have two versions of Python installed.

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments?

Comment: @dspencer thanks!!!! Got it right now!

Comment: @jinsapearl If your problem has been solved, please consider accepting the answer. The comment section is not for extended discussions.

Comment: @dspencer I don’t know how to accept answer.

Comment: @jinsapearl You will find a "tick" icon underneath the up/down vote arrows. For future reference, you can use these arrows to indicate whether an answer provides a good solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the Python version you want to use for VS Code. See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

I would also recommend setting up virtual environments if you plan to do a significant amount of Python work.

Comment: Paul, what is a virtual environment what is benefits of set up?

Comment: @jinsapearl The comments are not an appropriate place for discussions like this. You should do some research, then create a new question if necessary.

Comment: A virtual environment is an isolated Python installation including associated packages. It allows you to freeze the python version and libraries when you develop. If you develop multiple Python applications, all using the same version and packages you will run into conflicts. Google it for a more in depth explanation.

Comment: @paul I am a total beginner even just using python and vs code made me feel so lost ... is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment discussion, you have two versions of python installed, 2.7.11 and 3.7.5.

To use 3.7.5, you need to execute it as `python3`. `python3 --version` gives the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to run `python --version` instead of `python3 --version`.You can use pyenv to set a global version of python. Once it’s done, you can just run `python --version`, and the result will be the version of your global python.

Pyenv only deals with the python installed by pyenv itself, so if you want to use it, you may reinstall the specific version you want via pyenv.

Pyenv is also a tool to manage your virtual environment, and I guess you can kill two birds with one stone. There are two friendly articles explaining the virtual environment and pyenv respectively.

- [What is pyenv and how to use it](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/).
- [What is virtual environment?](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/)

Answer (score 0):

Installing Python version 3+ does not overwrite Python 2. So you may have both versions configured on your system. To check the version of each, use:

```
python2 --version
python3 --version
```

To identify if one is defaulting *higher* than the other, you can use the following to trace the path of both versions.

```
which python2
which python3
```

Depending on how close the paths are to your root, one may be defaulting to the other.